# Rails remote patch request to update record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Trying to submit a remote patch request to update the 'status' parameter of a record in my database by clicking a link in a table of records but without refreshing the page and get a javascript response in return.

```
<%=link_to "Planned", procedure_path(procedure), data: { method: patch, remote: true, params: { status: "planned" }.to_param }%>
```

This throws an error though, I am probably missing something obvious.

Comment: What the error you got?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks goes to Rajesh for helping me on my way!
In the end I wanted to do this with a PATCH request as that is the new norm for this sort of updating in Rails4.
One thing that was missing was that because I'm updating the record i need to wrap it in a 'procedure' hash because this is what the form would usually do. 
Other than that I was getting an error because the "patch" method was not defined obviously had to make this a string and also put it outside of data: where it belonged.

This is my final code working as expected: :)

```
 <%=link_to "Planned", procedure_path(procedure), data: { params: { procedure: { status: "planned"} }.to_param }, :method => 'PATCH', remote: true%>
```

Answer (score 1):

`remote: true` needs to be outside

```
<%= link_to "Planned", procedure_path(procedure), method: :put, remote: true, params: { status: "planned" }.to_param %>
```

Comment: Thanks rajesh your example really helped me on my way!!

Answer (score 0):

The update action requires PUT method. Try using following code

```
<%=link_to "Planned", procedure_path(procedure), data: { method: patch, params: { status: "planned" }.to_param }, :method => 'PUT', remote: true%>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your help but in rails4 you are supposed to make these sort of requests with the new PUSH verb as you are only updating certain parameters in the record not the whole record